# Insightful educational games about mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, education, book-recommendation, big-list, online-resources

In [this question on Physics stackexchange, I asked about educational games for physical phenomena such as in QM or Relativity.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394424/insightful-educational-games-about-physics)

Now I'm thinking, there could be good math games as well. For example, the game "Miegakure" is a 4-dimensional puzzle game that unfortunately is not released yet.

So my idea is to **create a list of (educational) video games that successfully and insightfully convey (counter-intuitive) mathematical concepts** (such as 4D space), which one can use alongside a formal training in mathematics.

- Simple games for children don't suffice. The games have to be about "relatively advanced" ideas such as 4D space.
- The games don't have to be officially "educational", but they should be about serious mathematical concepts. (e.g. "Miegakure" seems like an entertainment game, but it is still a serious attempt to model 4D space).
- My intention is not to use them as substitutes for, but as a complement to formal mathematical training, i.e. as a way to boost intuition for someone who also studies the topic formally.

Comment: I do not think that this question is actually about mathematics. Would vote to close if the bounty would not prevent it.

Comment: @Peter, it is about math eductation.

Comment: This question would fit better with https://matheducators.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Jeff Weeks has made a variety of games about geometry, often dealing with higher dimensional geometry and topology.  Here is his website: http://www.geometrygames.org/